# How can i solve "0 " value try to get length value?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

if i try to add int value into array with string length Whole data is "0" why? and how can solve it?

```
  for (int j = 0; j < dTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    mycounter[i] = dTable.Rows[i][j].ToString().Length;
                }
```

it is not related to mycounter because:

```
  string test = "";
           foreach(DataColumn dc in dTable.Columns)
                for (int i = 0; i < dTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                   // MessageBox.Show(dTable.Rows[i][dc].ToString());
                    test = dTable.Rows[i][dc].ToString().Length.ToString();
                }
```

Comment: It may be obvious to someone with more C# experience...but my first thought was: What is the datatype of `dTable` and `mycounter`? The more information you provide with your questions, the better people can help you.

Comment: mycounter must be some descendant of IEnumerable<int>, like a List<int>.

Comment: I'm not sure what your update even means. You set test to the last column in the last row and.... ?

Comment: What kind of data stored in DataTable?

Comment: So in your update, you mean to say: When I inspect test, the value is always "0".
Right?

Answer (score 2):

In  mycounter[]  you will have only values from last column of table.
May be last column contains empty strings?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Orsol said, the fact that you're looping through both dimensions seems to indicate that you want a total length for each row, and therefore,

```
mycounter[i] = dTable.Rows[i][j].ToString().Length;
```

should be changed to

```
mycounter[i] += dTable.Rows[i][j].ToString().Length;
```

It is also possible that the `ToString()` method is returning empty strings. Perhaps you're looking for a `Text` property?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are redeclaring mycounter between the for loops, you are overwriting mycounter[i] for each column 0 to Columns.Count-1 until the last column.

Did you want to sum the lengths? Or did you maybe want a 2-dimensional array for mycounter?